# Simple method call: The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I just stumbled upon an error I cannot explain.

The following code causes a compiler error in Visual Studio 2015:

```
class Program {
  private static void DoSomethingWithParameter(string s) { }

  private static void RegisterMethod<T>(Action<T> method) { }

  static void Main(string[] args) {
    RegisterMethod(DoSomethingWithParameter);
  }
}
```

Error:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Program.RegisterMethod<T>(Action<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

If I change the method call to

```
RegisterMethod<string>(DoSomethingWithParameter);
```

it works.

I think the compiler should be able to infer the correct type from the first method call, but that's not the case. Can anybody explain this to me, please?

Comment: If you don't specify type explicitly then `RegisterMethod(s => DoSomethingWithParameter(s))` will fail to compile. `s` is `T` not string. and method groups are just syntactic sugar of some lambda expressions.

Comment: Thanks @patrick-hofman. The linked topic resolved the question.